# Read MS Access from Excel using Binary.Buffer to avoid errors accessing db in Admin mode

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

I have an Excel spreadsheet "Report.xlsx" which reads data from MS Access "Database.accdb".  Within Report.xlsx, I wrote a simple macro "Macro1" which refreshes the data table in the spreadsheet.

Within MS Access, I am connecting to Excel and launching the macro.

This process fails with the following error in Excel:

```
DataFormat.Error: The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'BRNMBL0324' that prevents it from being opened or locked.
Details:
    Portal front-end extracts.accdb
```

Here is the MQuery that fails:

```
let
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("Database.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    #"Table 1" = Source{[Schema="",Item="My database table"]}[Data]
in
    #"Table 1"
```

If I read the database using a Binary.Buffer (per https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67852ccf-3c04-42c7-ac5c-6213d4d7b3a2/the-database-has-been-placed-in-a-state-by-user-8216admin8217-on-machine8230-that-prevents?forum=powerquery), the process works:

```
let
    MyDbBinary = Binary.Buffer(File.Contents("Database.accdb")),
    Source = Access.Database(MyDbBinary, [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    #"Table 1" = Source{[Schema="",Item="My database table"]}[Data]
in
    #"Table 1"
```

Since there is only one query in the spreadsheet, I am confident that the issue is not concurrent queries.  I closed and reopened the Access db, so I know that the issue is not an unsaved object in MS Access.

Is using Binary.Buffer a robust way of addressing this issue?

Comment: Does this same error happen when you refresh the query from the Excel file normally and the Access file is closed? The impact of using Binary.Buffer is that you are loading the entire Access DB into memory, as opposed to only having the results of the query operations hitting memory. It's plausible that could lead to issues depending what else is going on and how big the database is.

Comment: The problem does not occur if Access is closed.  I guess that raises a workaround -- maybe I could close the database and then kick off the Excel macros.  I don't know how to do that because my VBA code is running in Access, so I'd have to disconnect the VBA project with the Access db that I'm using.

Comment: It is VERY useful to know that Binary.Buffer loads the db into memory.  I was afraid of this, and I agree it's not optimal.  I'd love to fix this because this is a recurring problem for me and others at my company.

Comment: What is the purpose of remotely refreshing the query like this? You can configure a query to automatically refresh whenever the Excel file is opened (no macros necessary) if you're just trying to ensure the latest data is loaded. I guess another thing to test is if this error happens when the database is open and the Excel file is refreshed from a different computer. Also I don't know much about Access but I am assuming it has been set to Shared and not Exclusive mode (that generates a different error in my tests, so I doubt it's that).

Comment: Auto refresh is not an option because users who don't have the ability to connect to the db need to use the spreadsheet and see the most recent data.

Comment: To answer your second question, I get the same error on another computer.